# How can i get an ID from a select multiple using Element?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, element

I have a `select` for `persons` assigned to a `proyect`, so i need to send the `ID` from the `object` selected to a `function` i tried:

```
 <el-form-item label="Assign to:" prop="person">
                <el-select v-model="form.persons"  multiple value-key="id"  id="person_id" @change="getData()" placeholder="Select Personal" class="max-input" filterable>
                  <el-option  v-for="person in orderedPersons"  
                            :label="person.name +' '+ person.last_name" 
                            :key="person.id"
                            :value="person">
                  </el-option>
                </el-select>
```

Array persons:

```
form: { persons: [],}
```

Method

```
getData() {
   var pid;
   this.pid = document.getElementById("person_id").value;
   console.log(pid);
  this.$axios.get("/person/hasproject/" + this.pid ).then(response => {
    try {             
      notifications_success(response.data.userMessage);
    } catch (error) {}
  });
},
```

The `pid` (person id) is undefined and i can't find a solution for my case, i will appreciate help and comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are facing what is referenced in Vue.js documentation as [change detection caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats).

## Tl;dr

Due to the nature of javascript, Vue.js can't watch for changes inside objects. You have to tell him explicitly that some changes occured by using the provided method `Vue.set(object, key, value)`. You can give a try by using it, or avoiding it by, for example, doing so:

Template

```
 <el-form-item label="Assign to:" prop="person">
   <el-select
       multiple value-key="id"
       id="person_id"
       @change="getData()" // removed
       placeholder="Seleccione personal"
       class="max-input" filterable
     >
     <el-option  v-for="person in orderedPersons"  
       :label="person.name +' '+ person.last_name" 
       :key="person.id"
       :value="person.id"
       @click="updateData(person)" // added
     >
     </el-option>
  </el-select>
```

Script

```
form: { persons: []},

updateData(person) {
    for (const index in this.form.persons) {
        if (this.form.persons[i].id === person.id) {
            this.form.persons.splice(i, 1);
            // it was already inside, and we put it outside
            // the form.persons array, so we're done
            return 0;
        }
    }
    // If we are here, then person wasn't inside form.persons
    // So we add it
    this.form.persons.push(person);
    this.getDatas(person.id);
},
getData(id) {
    console.log(id);
    this.$axios.get("/person/hasproject/" + id )
    .then(response => {
      try {             
        notifications_success(response.data.userMessage);
      } catch (error) {}
  });
},
```

It's just a way to avoid the problem of detection caveat, but if I understand what you are trying to attempt, then it will probably be sufficient.

Comment: in dee, it is a event, one thing, i dont know if matter or not but the `el-option` value is `person` instead of `person.id`, i didnt getting a console answer neither

Comment: im edited the answer adding `click.native` but im still getting `[i]` undefined, thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

since the selected people are being populated through the v-model, you can access the person IDs by looking in your this.form.persons array and iterating through it.

So let's say

```
form: { 
 persons: [
  {name: "You", id: 1}, 
  {name: "Her", id: 2}, 
  {name: "Him", id: 3}
 ]
}
```

then you could do something like.

```
getData(){  
   this.form.persons.forEach(person=>{
    this.$axios.get("/person/hasproject/" + person.id )
        .then(//et cetera)

   })  
}
```

Comment: omg thanks!, thats the way, but i getting additional message when adding another person, if a have 3 persons then is showing 3 messages istead of one

Comment: that is because you have selected multiple and it is a for each. if you only want to get one, you could pass which one into get data like `getData(onePerson)`  and then wrap the axios call in `if (person.id === onePerson.id) { /*axios stuff */
}`